# Obtaining grouped max() or min() in Pandas without skipping NANs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Consider a sample dateframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : [1, 2, 2], 'x' : [1, 2, 3], 'y' : [2, 3, np.nan]})
```

If I want to get the max value of variable 'y' *without* skipping NANs, I would use the function:

```
df.y.max(skipna = False)
```

The returned results is *nan* as expected

However, if I want to calculate the grouped max value by 'group', as follows:

```
df.groupby('group').y.max(skipna = False)
```

I got an error message: *TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna'*

Seems like the DataFrameGroupBy.max() does not have the argument to skip nas. What would be the best way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to apply `pd.Series.max`:

```py
x = df.groupby("group")["y"].apply(pd.Series.max, skipna=False)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
group
1    2.0
2    NaN
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Another creative way, use negative infinity, `-np.inf`.

```
df.fillna(-np.inf).groupby('group')['y'].min().replace(-np.inf, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
group
1    2.0
2    NaN
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Only if your data doesn't have negative infinity values.